# jquery code change html closest not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

We create a script that gets the `innerHTML` of a element with specific class. This works perfect for the first `<table>`. But the script of table 1 is also applied on the second and third `<table>`.

I already tried to adding `.closest` to stay within the main `<table>`, but that is not working. All values of class `.myedit` are changing. Sadly the `.myedit` class is added dynamic so we can not create unique classes.

How can we change this?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cw8a2r5/30/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
    var sku = $('input:checked').closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
    $('input:checked').closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);
    });
    var sku = $('input:checked').closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
            $('input:checked').closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="image" rowspan="8">
                    <div class="myedit"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="order" colspan="2">Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <ul id="options-183-list" class="options-list">
                            <li class="product-option active">
                                <span class="input-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" checked="" name="options[183]" id="options_183_2" value="591" price="0">
                                </span>
                                <label for="options_183_2">
                                    <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                                    <span class="option-sku">SKU1</span>
                                    <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="product-option">
                                <span class="input-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[183]" id="options_182_2" value="590" price="0">
                                </span>
                                <label for="options_183_1">
                                    <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                                    <span class="option-sku">SKU2</span>
                                    <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="image" rowspan="8">
                    <div class="myedit"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="order" colspan="2">Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <ul id="options-181-list" class="options-list">
                            <li class="product-option active">
                                <span class="input-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" checked="" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="578" price="0">
                                </span>
                                <label for="options_181_2">
                                    <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                                    <span class="option-sku">SKU1</span>
                                    <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="product-option">
                                <span class="input-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="579" price="0">
                                </span>
                                <label for="options_181_1">
                                    <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                                    <span class="option-sku">SKU2</span>
                                    <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The code `var sku = $('input:checked')` is selecting all elements of that type. Is this intentional? Why not use `$(this)`?

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G Thanks, because we only want to use the elements that are checked.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?  Your question is very unclear + your html contains stuff that is not connected to the problem

Comment: @MihaiT I want to get the innerhtml of element `class="option-sku"` from the main input that is checked. And I want to display that innerhtml inside the `<div class="myedit">`. When changing the checked radio button, it should also change the innerhtml of `<div class="myedit">`. See my JS-fiddle. Just the same as the red color, only then with the inner html.

Comment: As per my above comment, you are selecting multiple elements, both to get `sku` and to assign the inner html. You need to use `this` to get the element you click only, then test if it is checked after.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G Can you please edit my JSFiddle to explain what you mean and how I can achieve that?

Comment: Something like `var radio = $(this); if (radio.prop("checked") == true)) var sku = radio.closest(`...etc . It's hard to edit your JSFiddle (and the snippet above) because it doesn't actually work - there are console errors because of the "opConfig" function referred to the inline "onclick" on the radio buttons is missing. BTW it's not a good practice to have jQuery style event handlers _and_ inline event handlers, especially on the same element. Choose a coding style and stick to it.

Comment: ADyson is correct, you should attend to `opConfig.reloadPrice()` first. Perhaps you were not aware of it thus making this a [XYZ Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you set a starting html to `myedit` by

```
var sku = $('input:checked').closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
    $('input:checked').closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);
```

jQuery will get the **first input:checked it finds** ( so the input from the first table ), and then fetch the html depending on that first input. It will NOT select each input and get the html depending on them.

So you could use an `each` function to select html depending on each input you have and pass it to the corresponding `myedit` div.

Second, on inputs you should use `change` event, not `click` event. Then check if by changing the input it became `:checked` or not, and then using `this` keyword find the html and pass it to the `myedit` div that is in the same table with the `changed` input.

I changed the content a bit so it will be more clear ( for example purposes only )

I agree, there might be a better or cleaner way to do this, but anyway, check below

```js
 $('input:checked').each(function() {
   let sku = $(this).closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
   $(this).closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);
 });


 $('input').change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     let sku = $(this).closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
     $(this).closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="image" rowspan="8">
        <div class="myedit"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="order" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input-box">
          <ul id="options-183-list" class="options-list">
            <li class="product-option active">
              <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" checked="" name="options[183]" id="options_183_2" value="591" price="0">
                        </span>
              <label for="options_183_2">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">content1 table1</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
            </li>
            <li class="product-option">
              <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[183]" id="options_182_2" value="590" price="0">
                        </span>
              <label for="options_183_1">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">content2 table1</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="image" rowspan="8">
        <div class="myedit"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="order" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input-box">
          <ul id="options-181-list" class="options-list">
            <li class="product-option active">
              <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" checked="" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="578" price="0">
                        </span>
              <label for="options_181_2">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">content1 table2</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
            </li>
            <li class="product-option">
              <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="579" price="0">
                        </span>
              <label for="options_181_1">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">content2 table2</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yup, like this :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var sku = $(this).closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
            $(this).closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);
        }
    });
    
    $('input:radio').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="image" rowspan="8">
                <div class="myedit"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="order" colspan="2">Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <ul id="options-183-list" class="options-list">
                        <li class="product-option active">
                            <span class="input-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" checked="" name="options[183]" id="options_183_2" value="591" price="0">
                            </span>
                            <label for="options_183_2">
                                <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                                <span class="option-sku">SKU1</span>
                                <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="product-option">
                            <span class="input-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" name="options[183]" id="options_182_2" value="590" price="0">
                            </span>
                            <label for="options_183_1">
                                <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                                <span class="option-sku">SKU2</span>
                                <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="image" rowspan="8">
                <div class="myedit"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="order" colspan="2">Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <ul id="options-181-list" class="options-list">
                        <li class="product-option active">
                            <span class="input-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" checked="" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="578" price="0">
                            </span>
                            <label for="options_181_2">
                                <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                                <span class="option-sku">SKU1</span>
                                <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="product-option">
                            <span class="input-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="579" price="0">
                            </span>
                            <label for="options_181_1">
                                <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                                <span class="option-sku">SKU2</span>
                                <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

have a look at this code.

So the most important thing here is the `$(this).closest()` which will really try to find closest elements from the current element.

Note: i have removed `opConfig.reloadPrice()` to run it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sku = $('input:checked').closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
  $('input:checked').closest('tbody').find('.myedit').html(sku);

  $('input').click(function() {

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.options-list').find('li').removeClass("active");
      $(this).closest('.product-option').addClass("active");
      var value = $(this).closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').text();
      $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('.myedit').text(value);
    }

  });
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/awpon801/15/)